# How to mock wcf service(transformed from asmx) by Moq

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, asmx, moq

I have Silverligth Unit test Application (.net 4.0) and I've added reference to my WCF service(3.5)

And here are my codes

MyService.svc

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="VB" Service="MyServiceWS.Service1" %>
```

MyService.asmx

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://schemas.mypage.co.uk/MyService")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://schemas.mypage.co.uk/MyService")> _
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(Member))> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
```

From reference.cs

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyServiceApp.MyServiceService.Service1>, MyServiceApp.MyServiceService.Service1 {
```

my testclass:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace MyServiceApp.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ShowroomLogViewModelTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReloadShowroomLogs_IsBusyShouldBeFalse()
        {
            var mockedWebService = Mock<IService1>;
```

Problem is that:

```
IService1 cannot be resolved
```

How can I mock my wcf service?

**EDIT: One Step Closer**

```
var mockedWebService =new Mock<MyService.Service1>;
```

I've changed to this and now is compiling, but...
I haven' access to method, e.g.

```
mockedWebService.GetShowroomLogs();
```

It is a big problem, because, I need change a property ServiceClient at ShowroomLogViewModel to interface, and I can't because then my viewmodel can't use wcf service methods.

Comment: I think you should do this: mockedWebService.Object.GetShowroomLogs();

Comment: Yes, that works. Add it as answer and I'll reward you :)

Comment: why the heck you using VB, that is trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this: mockedWebService.Object.GetShowroomLogs();